# How can I display image urls from JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've created a HTML page that displays JSON array data in table. The arrays includes ID, Title, and an image. It looks great but the image is currently just text, when I need it to display the actual image of the link. I have no idea how to tackle this.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="one_article" style="">
    <table id="article_table" class="table table-bordered ">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Cover Image</th>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<tr>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.cover+'</td>';
      article_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#article_table').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

Currently view:

[image]

Comment: You just need to put the `img` tag with the url from your JSON. `<img src=" '+ value.cover +' " >`

Answer (score 1):

Use `img` tag to display image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<tr>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td><img src="'+value.cover+'"></td>';
      article_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#article_table').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can wrap a link around that image to direct to a new page? Something like article_data += '<td> <a href="https://mylink.com"<img src="'+value.cover+'"> </a> </td>';

Answer (score 1):

Use the tag img src="" to show the image. The JS code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<tr>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td> <img src="'+value.cover+'"> </td>';
      article_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#article_table').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can wrap a link around that image to direct to a new page? Something like article_data += '<td> <a href="mylink.com"<img src="'+value.cover+'"> </a> </td>';

Comment: Yes, you could do exactly like that '<td><a href="http://yourlink.com"><img src="'+value.cover+'"></a></td>';

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Following to my first comment, just add `img` tag like usual in your `td`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("article.json", function(data){
    console.log(data) //just to log in console as well
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<tr>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td><img src="'+value.cover+'"></td>';
      article_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#article_table').append(article_data);
  });
});
```

Comment: So quick! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I can wrap a link around that image to direct to a new page? Something like article_data += '<td> <a href="mylink.com"<img src="'+value.cover+'"> </a> </td>';

Comment: yeah your code is correct `<a href="mylink.com"><img src="'+value.cover+'"> </a>`. You're just missing a closing `>` in your `a tag`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate the help so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [
      {
       "id":1,
       "title":"title1",
       "cover":"https://dummyimage.com/300"
      },
      {
       "id":2,
       "title":"title2",
       "cover":"https://dummyimage.com/200"
      },
      {
       "id":3,
       "title":"title3",
       "cover":"https://dummyimage.com/400"
      }
    ];
    var article_data = '';
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
      article_data += '<tr>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
      article_data += '<td><img src="'+value.cover+'"></td>';
      article_data += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#article_table').append(article_data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="one_article" style="">
    <table id="article_table" class="table table-bordered ">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Cover Image</th>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```